# Expand zpool vdev

Tags: zfs

Hello I'm looking to expand my vdev and I'm confused about what command I need to do this. Here is what I have

```
  pool: DATA01
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 0 days 07:43:11 with 0 errors on Sun Aug 14 08:07:15 2022
config:

        NAME                                          STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        DATA01                                        ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz2-0                                    ONLINE       0     0     0
            /dev/sda                                  ONLINE       0     0     0
            /dev/sdb                                  ONLINE       0     0     0
            /dev/sdc                                  ONLINE       0     0     0
```

And here is what I want (one additional drive).

```
  pool: DATA01
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 0 days 07:43:11 with 0 errors on Sun Aug 14 08:07:15 2022
config:

        NAME                                          STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        DATA01                                        ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz2-0                                    ONLINE       0     0     0
            /dev/sda                                  ONLINE       0     0     0
            /dev/sdb                                  ONLINE       0     0     0
            /dev/sdc                                  ONLINE       0     0     0
            /dev/sdd                                  ONLINE       0     0     0
```

The add command seems to only be for creating new vdevs, e.g, raidz2-1 and the attach command only seems to be for mirrors.

Thanks in advance.

```
     zpool add [-fgLnP] [-o property=value] pool vdev...
             Adds the specified virtual devices to the given pool.  The vdev specification is described in the Virtual Devices section.  The behavior of the -f option, and the de‐
             vice checks performed are described in the zpool create subcommand.

     zpool attach [-f] [-o property=value] pool device new_device
             Attaches new_device to the existing device.  The existing device cannot be part of a raidz configuration.  If device is not currently part of a mirrored configuration,
             device automatically transforms into a two-way mirror of device and new_device.  If device is part of a two-way mirror, attaching new_device creates a three-way mir‐
             ror, and so on.  In either case, new_device begins to resilver immediately.
```

Answer (score -1):

Use google - there no such feature in zfs for now.

https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2021/06/raidz-expansion-code-lands-in-openzfs-master

https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/pull/12225

Comment: I've read that article but I thought it was already hear. Booo!

Comment: Also, sorry, I can't give you a vote since your answer was snarky.

Comment: After reading you should have checked it
   https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/pull/12225

Comment: Your question is like you don't know there is no such feature pretending you just don't know what command to use. You should have to ask about feature is already available.

Comment: Cool man, hope you enjoy being a dick.